# In javafx how can I change between features with different fxml files?

Tags: java, css, xml, javafx

Here is what the program looks like now. https://github.com/TheLearningCurve/RevampNutritionAPI/issues/48

Eventually I will have icons to navigate between features. The problem that I am having is that I am not sure how to change the fxml files to show different features without loading them all at once then making them visible and not visible.

Here is the Frame.fxml code that has our first feature in it. You can see we have the FrameTopController, and the FrameLeftController , FrameRightController this makes up the Search feature. Eventually we will have a few more features but I have no clue where to begin. All of the features will be placed in the Frame.fxml if possible.

```
` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import nutritionAPIV2_controllers.*?>

<fx:root maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="549.0" prefWidth="832.0" type="javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>

        <!-- Top Panel -->

      <StackPane layoutY="70.0" prefHeight="479.0" prefWidth="832.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="70.0">
         <children>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="473.0" prefWidth="832.0">
               <children>
                  <SplitPane fx:id="navMenuPane" dividerPositions="0.0036144578313253013" layoutY="1.0" prefHeight="442.0" prefWidth="832.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="6.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="1.0">
                    <items>
                      <AnchorPane fx:id="navMenu" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="456.0" prefWidth="71.0" SplitPane.resizableWithParent="false" />
                      <AnchorPane fx:id="LeftandRightAnchor" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="489.0" prefWidth="763.0">
                           <children>
                              <HBox fx:id="LeftAndRightPanel" alignment="CENTER" layoutY="-9.0" prefHeight="479.0" prefWidth="824.0" spacing="1.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="-9.0">
                                 <children>
                                            <!-- Created by Brandon VanderMeyf May 20 2015 -->


                                                    <!-- Left Panel -->

                                                    <FrameBottomLeftController fx:id="frameBottomLeftController" />

                                                    <!--  Right Panel -->

                                                    <FrameBottomRightController fx:id="frameBottomRightController" />



                                 </children>
                              </HBox>
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                    </items>
                  </SplitPane>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
         </children></StackPane>
            <Pane prefHeight="64.0" prefWidth="833.0" style="-fx-background-color: #8bc34a;" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="-1.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
               <children>
               <FrameTopController fx:id="frameTopController" layoutX="450.0" layoutY="20.0" />
                  <AnchorPane layoutX="14.0" layoutY="19.0">
                     <children>
                        <Button id="menuButton" fx:id="menuButton" mnemonicParsing="false" opacity="0.37" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="38.0">
                           <effect>
                              <ImageInput>
                                 <source>
                                    <Image url="/resources/menuButton.png" />
                                 </source>
                              </ImageInput>
                           </effect>
                        </Button>
                        <Label layoutX="45.0" layoutY="-3.0"      prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="216.0" text="I'm A Program" textFill="WHITE">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="SansSerif Regular" size="24.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </children>
            </Pane>

    </children>
    </fx:root>`
```

What is the best practice for when the user clicks on the icon that the header where the search field is and the center of the Frame change to the next feature (Kind of like a mobile application)

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Here is the program...

https://github.com/TheLearningCurve/RevampNutritionAPI

Comment: can you elaborate sir

Comment: what do you mean by change xml? are you using fxml and scenebuilder? 
use fx:include but i am not sure if is this what you are asking.

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking. I recommend you read through some of the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), and edit your question so it is clearer.